# Update (a function) post's featured image as soon as $image_url changes

Tags: php, wordpress, function, thumbnails

I've been making a wordpress plugin which gets seperate instagram photos and then puts them in shortcodes. Though, the shortcodes display images not saved in WP images folder, but directly from instagram. It makes the server loading times drastically increase.

So I searched WP dev forums and found this function which sets the featured image for the specified post.

```
function Generate_Featured_Image( $image_url, $post_id  ){
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $image_data = file_get_contents($image_url);
    $filename = basename($image_url);
    if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path']))     $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
    else                                    $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
    file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
    $res1= wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
    $res2= set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
}
```

What am I missing is the fact that the photos I take get updated shortly and the featured image doesn't change after that. Would there be any way to update the featured image as soon as a new instagram photo gets uploaded? Or just every hour or so. Thanks a bunch, guys!

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
if( !function_exists( 'Generate_Featured_Image' ) ){
    function Generate_Featured_Image($image, $post_id, $setthumb='false', $post_meta = '') {
        // check to make sure its a successful upload
        if ($_FILES[$image]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

        $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $image, $post_id );

        if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
        if(!$setthumb && $post_meta!=''){
            update_post_meta($post_id, $post_meta, array( $attach_id ));
        }
        return $attach_id;
    }   
}
```

Not tested but you can take a look you can make your additional codes like `file_get_contents` etc..